# Why am I getting a Value error and negative dimension size on my python code (cnn_model)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Error :

```
File "C:\Users\Ayeh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\Ayeh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1969, in _create_c_op
    raise ValueError(e.message)
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "conv2d_2" (type Conv2D).
```

Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for '{{node conv2d_2/Conv2D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 3, 3, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](Placeholder, conv2d_2/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes: [?,1,1,32], [3,3,32,64].

Call arguments received by layer "conv2d_2" (type Conv2D):
� inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 1, 1, 32), dtype=float32)

This is my cnn_model

```
# Part 1 - Building the CNN
#importing the Keras libraries and packages
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras import optimizers

# Initialing the CNN
classifier = Sequential()

# Step 1 - Convolutio Layer 
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3,  3, input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))

#step 2 - Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size =(2,2)))

# Adding second convolution layer
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3,  3, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size =(2,2)))

#Adding 3rd Concolution Layer
classifier.add(Convolution2D(64, 3,  3, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size =(2,2)))


#Step 3 - Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())

#Step 4 - Full Connection
classifier.add(Dense(256, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))
classifier.add(Dense(26, activation = 'softmax'))

#Compiling The CNN
classifier.compile(
              optimizer = optimizers.SGD(lr = 0.01),
              loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics = ['accuracy'])

#Part 2 Fittting the CNN to the image
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'mydata/training_set',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'mydata/test_set',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical')

model = classifier.fit_generator(
        training_set,
        steps_per_epoch=800,
        epochs=25,
        validation_data = test_set,
        validation_steps = 6500)

'''#Saving the model
import h5py
classifier.save('Trained_model.h5')'''

print(model.history.keys())
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# summarize history for accuracy
plt.plot(model.history['acc'])
plt.plot(model.history['val_acc'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
# summarize history for loss

plt.plot(model.history['loss'])
plt.plot(model.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You pass strides = 3, and use pool size of 2. After the second max pooling the shapes are already reduced to (batch_size, 1, 1, 32).

Answer (score 0):

If the `padding` argument is not specified, it will default to `valid`, which means that the automatic dimensionality reduction that occurs during convolution will be present. If you use this model to calculate that for a 64x64 image with automatic dimensionality reduction, you'll get negative dimensions. To ensure that you get the same dimensionality after convolution as you did before, set `padding=same` when specifying Conv2D and pooling layers. Kindly change the model like below

```
classifier = Sequential()

# Step 1 - Convolutio Layer 
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3,  3, input_shape = (64, 64, 3),padding='same', activation = 'relu'))

#step 2 - Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size =(2,2)))

# Adding second convolution layer
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3,  3, activation = 'relu',padding='same',))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size =(2,2)))

#Adding 3rd Concolution Layer
classifier.add(Convolution2D(64, 3,  3, activation = 'relu',padding='same',))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size =(2,2),padding='same',))


#Step 3 - Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())

#Step 4 - Full Connection
classifier.add(Dense(256, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))
classifier.add(Dense(2, activation = 'softmax'))
```

I have tried to replicate the error using covid xray dataset, please refer the gist [here](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/synandi/dde819fdede285ce72a73bf6ad6658a8/untitled201.ipynb). Thank you!